# Fc2レンタルサーバーでOpenPNE3をインストールする

Tags: linux

Fc2レンタルサーバーでOpenPNE3をインストールする予定なのですが下記のコマンドを入力してもエラーが出てしまいます。

```
git clone git://github.com/openpne/OpenPNE3.git
```

以下エラー内容

> The program 'git' is currently not installed. To run 'git' please ask your administrator to install the package 'git-core'
>   giitd@rentalserver14:~/httpdocs$ The program 'git' is currently not installed. To run 'git' please ask your administrator to install the package 'git-core'^C

GITがインストールされていないことは理解出来ましたが

Fc2レンタルサーバーにGITはインストールできるのでしょうか？
できるのであれば参考サイトなどありましたら教えて下さい

Comment: 本題からは外れますが、git を使うのではなく、ZIP 形式のソースコードをダウンロードしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`git`はインストールできません。(管理者権限を与えられる`VPS`等を使うのが良いでしょう。基本的にレンタルサーバーでは与えられないかと思います。)

ところで、ソースコード自体は以下のように`zip`でも配信されていますので、そちらを利用する手はあるかと思います。

https://github.com/openpne/OpenPNE3/archive/master.zip

Comment: 助言ありがとうございます！
うまく行けました！